# Using async pipe looses reference to object type

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I have a simple problem. When I'm using async pipe in template IDE don't know what type has the object from the async pipe.

Here is a short example:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="(state$ | async).foo as foo">
```

Actually foo is of type `Foo: {id:string, name:string, value: number}`

The problem is, when I want to use `foo` in template IDE don't know that foo has id, or name, or value.

Is there any clean solution to "cast" `foo` to `Foo`?

Comment: If you define foo in your component ts as Foo does your IDE pick it up?

public foo: Foo;

Comment: I dont see how this could help :/ 
This isn't a good solution in my opinion

Comment: @Lamp define a variable to hold the value of $state is not a good practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as foo` statement is create a template variable not for casting ,if you use like this

```
   <ng-container *ngIf="(state$ | async).foo.id">
```

you will get type intellisense but when you create a template variable this information seem to be lost.

this consider a bug and may be solve in future.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="($state | async) as foo">
    {{foo | json}}
    <div>
        {{foo.id}} <!-- foo has no type information-->
    </div>

  {{value.name}} <!-- declared property has type information-->
</ng-container>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-type-flow)

Comment: okay, so there is no way to cast this. Now I understand. What a pity that this isn't resolved yet. In my opinion that will be the great feature.

Comment: As far I know there is no way to do casting in the template :\

Comment: okay, so I will wait a bit, maybe someone would have some solution. But generally, I will mark your answer as correct after this time. Thanks for help ;)

Comment: @MaciejWójcik thanks , can you consider mark this answer as correct?

Comment: This answer should point to a bug ticket if there is one

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, I have to fill a table. So I solved this problem creating a row component, and passing each array element as an input (typed) property like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446740/how-to-add-row-component-in-table-in-angular-7). Hope this help and, maybe, you should consider this solution as the only one correct right now, since the accepted one actually doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: hey, sorry but this is really a workaround in a very specific scenario - the loosing type issue still exists

Comment: well, you can apply my proposal to your scenario as well, you can create a component inside your ng-container and pass your variable as an input parameter and you'll get the typed variable with all its references, so I still think this is the only workaround for now, and it's more valid than the accepted one, just try it and you'll see :)